# 2012 R2 NPS/RADIUS Server. Event ID 4402: There is no domain controller available for the domain

Tags: windows

Attempting to replace existing Winidows 2003 RADIUS server with new 2012 R2 NPS/RADIUS Server.  RADIUS server used for 2nd Factor SafeWord authentication.  All policies and settings replicated to new NPS server.  NPS server has been registered w/ AD (***child.domain.com***).

When testing w/ **NTRadPing** Utility, continually get response: **Access-Reject**.  Event ID **4402** *"There is no domain controller for the domain* ***domain.com***" logged in System Log on NPS server.

Unable to locate any reference to issue w/ child domains.  Not sure if this error is perhaps a red herring of some sort.

Comment: Checking further, it appears this issue is a result of the customer having a NetBIOS domain name (pre-Windows 2000) that includes a "." (<domain>.com).

Microsoft reportedly dropped support for this in NPS with the release of Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what others have said, you do not need to rename your domain or back rev to 2008 non-R2.

I was able to resolve this issue by adding the following reg key to force authentication to use the **DNS** name, instead of the **NetBIOS** name:

**HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\PPP\ControlProtocols\Builtin**

- New String Value (REG_SZ):  ***DefaultDomain***
- Data:  ***example.loc*** (or ***example.domain.loc***)